# Merge two HashMaps in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to create

`def MergeWith[Id, X, Y, Z](x: HashMap[Id, X], y: HashMap[Id, Y], f: (X, Y) => Z): HashMap[Id, Z]`

I want to:

1) iterate over x

2) for keys that are presented in y yield `f(x[key], y[key])` into a result: `HashMap[Id, Z]`

For everything I invent I get compilation errors I don't understand how to fight.

For example,

```
def andWith[K, X, Y, Z] (x: HashMap[K, X], y: HashMap[K, Y], f: (X, Y) => Z): HashMap[K, Z] = {
  for {
    (x_name, x_value) <- x
    if y.contains(x_name)
  } yield x_name -> f(x_value, y.get(x_name))
}
```

produces

```
Error:(14, 39) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Y]
 required: Y
 } yield x_name -> f(x_value, y.get(x_name))
                              ^
```

which is predictable, but I fail to unwrap Option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a very concise and reasonably idiomatic way of writing this in Scala:

```
def mergeWith[K, X, Y, Z](xs: Map[K, X], ys: Map[K, Y])
  (f: (X, Y) => Z): Map[K, Z] =
    xs.flatMap {
      case (k, x) => ys.get(k).map(k -> f(x, _))
    }
```

Note that I'm using `Map` instead of `HashMap` and that I've changed some of the identifier names slightly. I've also put the function into its own parameter list, which can make the syntax a little cleaner for the user.

This is pretty dense code, so I'll unpack what's going on a bit. For every key-value pair `(k, v)` in the `xs` map, we use `ys.get(k)` to get an `Option[Y]` that will be `Some[Y]` if the key exists in `ys` and `None` otherwise. We use `map` on the `Option` to change the `Y` value inside (if it exists) into a pair `(K, Z)`.

The value of the entire `ys.get(k).map(k -> f(x, _))` part is therefore `Option[(K, Z)]`, which is a collection of exactly one or zero pairs. If we had used `map` on our `xs`, we'd have ended up with a `Seq[Option[(K, Z)]]`, but because we've used `flatMap`, this can be collapsed into a `Map[K, Z]`, which is what we want (and what we've specified as the return type of the method.

We can try it out:

```
scala> val mapX = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2)
mapX: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2)

scala> val mapY = Map('b -> "foo", 'c -> "bar")
mapY: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,String] = Map('b -> foo, 'c -> bar)

scala> mergeWith(mapX, mapY) { (x, y) => (x, y) }
res0: Map[Symbol,(Int, String)] = Map('b -> (2,foo))
```

Which is what we wanted.

Comment: `very concise` ...